# Facebook: Listening songs on Spotify of firends or me always return empty array (music)

Tags: facebook, spotify

I'm trying to get the current user's listens and friends listens.

I am sure my friends has listened songs on Spotify and those songs has been synced to Facebook, and I also could see it on my music tag. But when I use the `/me/music` call link I just get my liked music playlist, no friends listens, also no artist songs even though I have several favorite artists.

And I try to use friend uid to get his music, use the `/<friend-uid>/music` link, but return empty list even though he has listened more songs on Spotify and I could see those songs in my music wall.

Of course, I grant all the user permission for access token and make all my private permission to 'public'

Is Facebook API not support to get music info till now? Or am I missing something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ask for the user_actions.music and friends_actions.music to access the listened songs in Open Graph.

They're documented here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/permissions/

Answer (score 0):

From everywhere i've looked, it seems to be still in development and not readily able to pull. Which is a bummer.